# Emploi : « équivalent » ou « équivalant » ?

Tags: usage, homonymes

Je me demande quelle tournure est la correcte :

> Je détiens un Master Mécanique *équivalent* Magistère.

ou

> Je détiens un Master Mécanique *équivalant au* Magistère.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je pense que la formulation correcte serait :

> Je détiens un Master Mécanique équivalant à un Magistère.

Dans ce cas on utilise le participe présent car équivalant n'est pas employé comme un  adjectif mais comme un verbe.

Par ailleurs à moins qu'il ait été fait référence à un Magistère spécifique avant cette phrase, la forme indéterminée *à un* est préférable à *au*. On peut utiliser *équivalent*, mais il faut reformuler et on attend une suite à la phrase :

> Je détiens un Master Mécanique, un équivalent du Magistère [...]

Answer (score 0):

Complement à la réponse :

> 1- Équivalent(e) : c’est un adjectif ou un nom, selon les cas.
>   Exemples : ‘ Ces deux sommes sont équivalentes ‘ (adjectif). ‘ Il a
>   vendu aujourd’hui l’équivalent des ventes d’une semaine entière ‘
>   (nom).
>
> 2- Équivalant : c’est le participe présent invariable du verbe ‘
>   équivaloir ‘. ‘ Équivalant ‘ = ‘ qui équivaut ‘. Exemple : ‘ Son
>   travail fourni aujourd’hui équivalant (= qui équivaut) à 7 heures, cet
>   employé sera payé 7 heures.’

Source :

http://lebonusage.over-blog.com/article-les-homophones-equivalent-et-equivalant-73738482.html

ou

http://alorthographe.unblog.fr/2010/05/10/les-homophones-equivalent-et-equivalant/

Voir aussi :

https://www.cordial.fr/dictionnaire/definition/%C3%A9quivalent.php